# Is there a way to convert an object to json or other printable format?

Tags: ruby

I have an object, and I want to dump all its information.

For debugging purpose, can I convert it to json or other suitable format?

I know using p object, sometimes can print out all its information; but not always. So I am asking is there other ways when p object becomes invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [pry](http://pryrepl.org/)

It is excellent for exploring objects. Especially large objects because it has paging. The objects are also color coded to make it more readable.

Steps:

1. install pry
2. Add require 'pry' to the script file you want to debug
3. Add binding.pry below the object declaration of anywhere the object is in scope
4. Run your script
5. This will pop open the pry console with access to your object
6. Type in the object name
7. 'ls object' will list all the instance variables of the object

Answer (score 1):

There's couple ways you can go. Using json from the standard lib is one way to convert an object to json.

this converts an object in ruby to a json string:

`require "json"
h = Hash.new(name: "example")
JSON.dump(h)`

But you seem to be wanting to inspect an object in detail. The best solution is probably the "Pry" gem that others have suggested if you really need a lot of detail.
so after installing pry you can "cd" into objects and inspect instance variables public/private methods and the source code of methods/classes, etc. its really great stuff.

`require "pry"
cd SomeObject
ls # this shows you everything defined in the object.`

The problem with object.inspect that others have suggested is that it can be overriden, often is, and thus will oft not show you enough information. So it depends on what you want to find out.

`puts o.instance_variables #=> shows all an objects instance variable names
puts o.instance_variable_get :@some_var #=> returns the value held by @some_var
puts o.methods - Object.methods #=> roughly speaking, shows you the methods defined on an object itself and not inheritted from parent objects`

Unfortunately there's not a perfect answer here, but for debugging purposes I personally think nothing beats out pry especially with the pry debugger addon gem (forgot actual name) that allows you to step through the call stack.

Comment: The pry debugger gem is pry-byebug. Nth-ing the usefulness of these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "inspect" : "Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of obj. By default, show the class name and the list of the instance variables and their values (by calling inspect on each of them). "

Example:

```
puts object.inspect
```

Comment: This should be same as p object, right? I found this does not work all the time, some object only display 1 instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `puts my_object.as_json.to_json`

Comment: this will only work in rails or any environment that includes libraries that dynamically add the as_json and to_json methods. For most gems, and ruby projects this will not work.